# A real symmetric matrix with less than $n$ distinct eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix with less than $n$ distinct eigenvalues, is it true that for any $\vec{v}$, $\{\vec{v},A\vec{v},...,A^{n-1}\vec{v}  \}$ is always linearly dependent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is always the case (assuming $A$ is $n\times n$).

Since $A$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable. Since it has fewer than $n$ distinct eigenvalues, at least one eigenspace of $A$ must have at least two dimensions. Which is to say, there is an eigenbasis for $A$ (being careful to choose the basis vectors from the multidimensional eigenspace) such that $v$ expressed in that basis has one component equal to $0$. And this will also be true of all $A^kv$, and any linear combination of them. Since we have $n$ vectors that do not span all of $n$-dimensional space, they must be linearly dependent.

Comment: How can you choose that eigenbasis? Why is it always true that you can set one component to be 0?

Comment: @Joe Start with _some_ eigenbasis. Let the first two vectors of that basis be two eigenvectors of $A$ with the same eigenvalue, and let $v=(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$ in this basis. If either $v_1=0$ or $v_2=0$, then we're done. If not, make a new basis where the first vector is, in the original eigenbasis, given by $(v_1,v_2,0,\ldots,0)$, the second basis vector is $(v_1,0,0,\ldots,0)$ and the rest of the basis vectors are unchanged. Then $v$ in this new basis will be $(1,0,v_3,v_4,\ldots,v_n)$.

Comment: Alternately, $v$ can be decomposed into a linear combination of eigenvectors of $A$, all with distinct eigenvalues. Start with these vectors, and expand that to an eigenbasis. In this basis, $v=(1,1,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, it is diagonalizable.  Therefore it satisfies $p(A) =0$ where $p(\lambda) = \prod_i (\lambda- \lambda_i)$, $\lambda_i$ the distinct eigenvalues.  This has degree $\le n-1$, so $ 0 = p(A) v$ is a nontrivial linear combination of $v, Av, \ldots, A^{n-1} v$.